# Gradle (v 2.5) command is failing after few executions with IBM JDK 1.6

Tags: gradle

I am getting after few run the gradle command few times. When I checked in Task Manager I see some hanging java instances. This is happening with IBM JDK 1.6.
When I changed it to Sun JDK 1.7 the command is running properly.

I currently need to restart my System to fix it. Request you to kindly help me.

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not start Gradle daemon.
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:109)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:117)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:23
7)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:21
0)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication.readDiagnostics(DaemonStartupCommunication.ja
va:100)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:133)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.InputStreamBackedDecoder.readBoolean(InputStreamBackedDecoder.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.AbstractDecoder.readNullableString(AbstractDecoder.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication.readDiagnostics(DaemonStartupCommunication.ja
va:85)
        ... 26 more
```